# Bootstrap validator regex issue

Tags: regex, twitter-bootstrap

My regular expression below needs a bit of tweaking.

Rules only allowing:

- letters (upper and lowercase)
- whitespace
- double quotes

**So the following would pass:**

```
Sales Manager
Sales
"Sales Manager"
Sales AND Manager
```

My current regex is allowing

```
Sales6848383
Sales<script etc....
```

It seems to be only concerned about the first letter.

Here is my regex in its current state:

```
/[a-zA-Z \"]+/
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regex will do a partial match. You need to put anchors in-order to avoid partial string match.

```
/^[a-zA-Z \"]+$/
```